# Original Statement and Proof of Chebyshev’s $\vartheta(x) \sim x$

Tags: number-theory

I am looking for an online source that gives the original statement and proof of Chebyshev’s asymptotic relation $\vartheta(x)\sim x$ where $\vartheta(x)=\sum_{p\leq x}\log p$.

I have tried searching online but the multiple spellings of Chebyshev's name in Latin characters is a significant impediment. I have also looked at secondary sources but have not found one yet that gives a reference to the original paper by Chebyshev.

Any reference of the type described would be appreciated.

Comment: According to this page, he did not:
http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Chebyshev.html : "He was unable to prove, however, that (...), with (...) being equivalent to the prime number theorem (which Chebyshev's asymptotic relation is an equivalent of)

Answer (score 2):

@Vicache - Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I believe I can now answer my own question. The source of my answer is Hardy's book "Ramanujan" (reference below).

Chebyshev proved that the Prime Number Theorem  $\pi (x)$ ~ $\frac{x}{ln(x)}$ is equivalent to $\vartheta(x)$ ~ $x$ and he proved that if the limit of  $\frac{\vartheta(x)}{x}$ exists as $x\rightarrow\infty$ then the limit is $1$. However Chebyshev could not prove the existence of the limit.

The existence of the limit and hence the Prime Number Theorem and hence $\vartheta(x)$ ~ $x$ was finally proved by Hadamard and de la Vallée Poussin independently in 1896.

Reference:
Hardy, G., "Ramanujan", pp. 27-28, Chelsea,New York, 3e, 1978.

Answer (score 2):

Chebyshev introduced his functions $\theta(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ in his 1852 paper "Mémoire sur les nombres premiers". It is available online [here](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/JMPA/PDF/JMPA_1852_1_17_A19_0.pdf): $\theta(x)$ is on p. 368 and $\psi(x)$ is on p. 371. In section V he bounds $\psi(x)$ above and below by expressions that are asymptotic to $Ax$ (lower bound) and $(6/5)Ax$ (upper bound), where
$A \approx .921$ is given by an explicit formula in the middle of p. 376. The bounds together are on the bottom of page 378.  He converts this into upper and lower bounds on $\theta(x)$ on p. 379.

In this paper, Chebyshev does *not* write about an equivalence between $\pi(x) \sim x/\log x$ and estimates on $\psi(x)$ or $\theta(x)$.  He does write on p. 389 about getting bounds from above and below on the number of primes between $\ell$ and $L$ using bounds on $\theta(x)$ (see equation (9)), but he doesn't directly write $Cx/\log x < \pi(x) < C'x/\log x$ for constants $C$ and $C'$.

In another paper that appeared in 1852, "Sur la totalité des nombres premiers inférieurs à une limite donnée", which can be found online [here](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/JMPA/PDF/JMPA_1852_1_17_A18_0.pdf), Chebyshev shows that if $\pi(x)/(x/\log x)$ has a limit then this limit must be $1$, although he does not write the result exactly in that form. See Theorem II on p. 348 and also pp. 356-357.

Narkiewicz, in his book *The Development of Prime Number Theory*, describes  the form of the prime number theorem that appeared in the proofs by Hadamard and de la Vallee Poussin as $\theta(x) \sim x$ (see pp. 201 and 216) and writes in a footnote on p. 217 that "it seems" Sylvester in 1892 was the first to observe that $\theta(x) \sim x \Longrightarrow \pi(x) \sim x/\log x$. I find it hard to believe nobody before Sylvester was aware of that, including Chebyshev, but please note that it does *not* appear that Chebyshev ever wrote down such a result.  Unless Hardy gave an actual reference to a paper of Chebyshev in what you had read, don't accept that Chebyshev really did prove an equivalence between $\pi(x) \sim x/\log x$ and $\theta(x) \sim x$, or even an implication in one direction. I've never seen such an argument in one of Chebyshev's papers.

Comment: Hardy's claim (on p. 28 of *Ramanujan*) is that Chebyshev proved $(\log x)\pi(x) \sim \theta(x) \sim \psi(x)$. But in the end notes he gives no reference to any paper of Chebyshev's, but rather to textbooks: Ingham's *The distribution of prime numbers*, Landau's *Handbuch* and *Vorlesungen über Zahlentheorie*, and Hardy & Wright. I think Hardy just erred on the side of caution in over-attributing results to Chebyshev.

Comment: Thanks for the info especially the links to Chebyshev's original papers. 

I will defer to your knowledge of Chebyshev's papers and assume Hardy in "Ramanujan" did not have explicit evidence, at least not from Chebyshev's 1852 papers, for attributing to him a proof of the equivalence of θ(x)∼x  and  π(x)∼x/logx.

Who then did first publish an explicit proof of the equivalence ?

Comment: I mentioned a paper by Sylvester from 1892 about one direction of that equivalence. See Narkiewicz’s book for more bibliographic details on that.